# How to get dynamic data provided the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dynamic

Given I have the code below that fetch data from local file.

```
export function getData() {
    const promiseMSFT = fetch("http://localhost:8080/data.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        var tempData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //some code
       }
      return tempData;
    })  
    return promiseMSFT;
}
```

How can I convert this to fetch data dynamically from different/dynamic url?

Example, if I have these URL that gets generated:

```
url1 with data1
url2 with data2
url3 with data3
```

How can I get three result.

Comment: did you mean fetching data from multiple urls ?

Comment: i have added my answer

Comment: john did your problem got solved if yes accept the answer which solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
export function getData(url) {
 //if you have n urls
let URLS = []
let tempData = [];
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
  url = `site/test/${i}/data`
  URLS.push(url);
 }
return Promise.all(
  URLS.map(url => 
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(responseData => {
      //push data to temp data here
    })
    .catch(err => /* handle errors here */ console.error(err))
  )
).then(() => {// do stuff}, err => {// handle error})
}
```

Comment: accept it if its working else give feedback about the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

```
urlArr = [site/test/1/data.json, site/test/2/data.json, site/test/3/data.json]
export function getData(url) {
    const promiseMSFT = fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        var tempData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //some code
       }
      return tempData;
    })  
    return promiseMSFT;
}

urlArr.forEach(url=>{getData("http://"+url)})
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. But how can this relates to different url as im not using single url. please see my comment above. thanks!

Comment: interesting, can you please try to include it in your answer, so I can mark it as an accepted answer since, my question is related to how to fetch different/dynamic url.

Comment: thank but I might try aravind_reddy answer since Ive got hundreds of dynamic url.

Answer (score 0):

updating answer of @tung yu

```
export function getData(url) {
    const promiseMSFT = fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        var tempData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          //some code
       }
      return tempData;
    })  
    return promiseMSFT;
}
```

and then do this :

```
data1 = getData(url1)
data2 = getData(url2)
data3 = getData(url3)
```

for many urls :

```
var urls = [url1,url2, ....]; 
var dataitems = []; 
for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++) 
{ 
     dataitems[i] = getData(url[i]);
}
```

you will get final result here in 'dataitems' array

Comment: Doesnt seems to be a good idea if I hard code each. As I have hundreds of dynamic URL.

Comment: then you could try a loop for this, I am assuming you must have an array of urls:
`var urls = [url1,url2, ....];
var datas = [];
for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++)
{
datas[i] = getData(url[i]);
}`
so you will get final data in datas array